# How to create a property of a simple list of integers in SQLAlchemy without using Postgres's ARRAY feature

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am sure there is an easy way to do this but it seems I'm having trouble finding it.

I have an object that has a property that is a list of integers. I'm defining a simple many to one table to represent them.

```
independents = db.Table('independents', Base.metadata,
    db.Column('warehouse_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('warehouse.id')),
    db.Column('independent_rack', db.Integer))

class Warehouse(Base):
    independent_racks = # what goes here?
```

I'd like to create a simple list of independent racks as a list of integers under `Warehouse.independent_racks`, but I'm not sure how to configure the relationship or what it would be. Is this an association_proxy? I'm really not sure what to look for.

I am using PostgreSQL but I'd rather maintain some database agnosticism and it seems the ARRAY type is particular to Postgres.

One solution is to make `independents` into an object, define a relationship between `Warehouse` and the `Independents` object, and then create an association proxy to the `independent_rack` value, but this seems excessive, when I imagine there's a simple way to define a scalar of the values in the table. I can't find it.

Comment: did you check [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one) example?

Comment: But it's a table, not an object? Does the same syntax apply?

Comment: The database table "independents" needs to be associated with a (child) object. Then `independent_racks` can be a `relationship` in the parent (`Warehouse`) object.

Comment: I think I'm being misunderstood. I do not want a list of objects, I want a list of integers in independent_racks. I could create objects, and use an association_proxy to get the values, but that seems like more overhead than needed, when all I need to do is represent the values in the table as a list of integers

Comment: Take a look at this: https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.scalar_list